# DropdownList in EmptyDataRow and Footer data bind with SQL stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a GridView which allows me to insert a new row in the database table. I need to populate the dropdown for 'Approved By' with values from the same database table, but in the table, the approved_by column is stored as a unique ID number. A stored Procedure called 'GetWeldID' converts the number to a name which needs to be presented on the website.

This is my code:
    aspx page:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approved By">  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Approved" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("approved_by") %>'></asp:Label>  
                    </ItemTemplate>  

                     <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="tb_approved_by" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate> 
                </asp:TemplateField>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <tr>
                              <th></th>
                                <th>Serial Number</th>
                                <th>Approved By</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                 <td>
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btInsert" Text="Insert New In Scope Record" OnClick="Add" CommandName="EmptyDataTemplate" Class="Button" />
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btInsertOut" Text="Insert New Out of Scope Record" OnClick="AddOut" CommandName="EmptyDataTemplate" Class="Button" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb_Serial_Number" CssClass="text"></asp:TextBox>
                               </td>
                                <td><asp:DropDownList ID="tb_approved_by" runat="server">                    
                    </asp:DropDownList> </td>
                            </tr>
                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
```

aspx.cs page:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow)//for empty template
        {
            DropDownList ddlnewuser = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("tb_approved_by");
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT distinct [dbo].[getWeldName](approved_by) from " + databaseName + "", con);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(ds);
            ddlnewuser.DataSource = ds;
            ddlnewuser.DataTextField = "approved_by";
            ddlnewuser.DataValueField = "approved_by";
            ddlnewuser.DataBind();
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)//for footer template
        {
            DropDownList tb_approved_by = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("tb_approved_by");
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT distinct [dbo].[getWeldName](approved_by) from " + databaseName + "", con);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(ds);
            tb_approved_by.DataSource = ds;
            tb_approved_by.DataTextField = "approved_by";
            tb_approved_by.DataValueField = "approved_by";
            tb_approved_by.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

The error that I am getting is

> Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'approved_by'.

Once I've got this working, I then need to add the selected item in the dropdown list to my database, but convert the name back to the numeric ID number!!

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong so any help would be really appreciated as I am a beginner to ASP.NET, C# and SQL Server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are column names are in `SELECT distinct [dbo].[getWeldName](approved_by) from`

Comment: `[dbo].[getWeldName](approved_by)` is a user defined function I assume. In that case you have an unnamed column. Try putting an alias to that column like `SELECT distinct [dbo].[getWeldName](approved_by) AS 'approved_by'`

Comment: And also, both code are the same, to avoid code duplication, use an `OR` statement or a `switch/case`

Comment: I think we need to find out what getWeldName is first. A view or a function?

Comment: @WEI_DBA I think that it's a function because it comes BEFORE the FROM, if it was a view it would come after

Comment: This is the first time I've seen a database name in the From on a Select statement. The database name should precede the function name and remove the From.

Comment: getWeldName is a stored procedure in SQL. @Felipe Deguchi, using the 'AS 'approved_by'' worked!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dbo].getWeldName is a user defined function I assume. In that case you have an unnamed column. Try putting an alias to that column like SELECT distinct [dbo].getWeldName AS 'approved_by'